# Jquery Hide/Show Div based on data-x-toggleable

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons and I want to hide/show some other divs based on whether the user clicks each button.

```
<button id="tab-572-10" class="e572-10" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="panel-572-10" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-572-10" data-x-toggle-group="tab-group-e572-9" style="outline: none;"><span>Tab 1</span></button>

<button id="tab-572-11" class="e572-11 x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-572-11" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-572-11" data-x-toggle-group="tab-group-e572-9" style="outline: none;"><span>Tab 2</span></button>
```

I am trying to target the class of each button to identify which button the user has clicked

```
jQuery('button[data-x-toggleable]').on('click', function() {
  if (this.hasClass("e572-10")) {
    jQuery('div[id^=pr-mem]').show();
    jQuery('div[id^=co-mem]').hide(); 
  }
});
```

However I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.hasClass is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is

```
$(this).hasClass("..."); // jQuery
```

or

```
this.classList.contains("...."); // DOM
```